# Mathematica If-then vs. Implies

Tags: if-statement, wolfram-mathematica, boolean-logic

I am new to Mathematica(v8) and am using it to program propositional logic.

I'm wondering what the difference is between the `If` and the `Implies` operators. For example,
both `If[p,q]` and `Implies[p,q]` return `q` for `p=True` (as expected).

But when I try to obtain SatisfiabilityInstances, I get the following:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[If[p, q], {p, q}]
(*
  {{True, True}}
*)
```

unless I ask it for more instances:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[If[p, q], {p, q}, All]
```

> SatisfiabilityInstances::boolv: "If[p,q] is not Boolean valued at {False,True}.

However:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[Implies[p, q], {p, q}, All]
```

returns the expected out of:

```
(* {{True, True}, {False, True}, {False, False}} *)
```

What is causing this difference in the outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is what it said -- `If` is not Boolean, i.e. it returns not only true or false. Try `If[False,True]` and you'll see no result.  `If[a,b,c,d]` can return any b, c and d, not only Boolean, for example `If[True,2]` returns 2. So, `If` is for branching (even being functional) while `Implies` is a normal Boolean function.

P.S. Ah, `Implies` also can return `2`. So the difference is that `If[False,True]` returns nothing, so `SatisfiabilityInstances` function can't find true area.

P.P.S. More precisely, if the first argument of `If[]` is `False` then it returns it's third argument. When it is absent, it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you direct me to a good tutorial? I've read the Mathematica Documentation but wasn't aware that it's possible to give 'If' four values (only three for if-else). 'If[a,b,c,d]' returns 'd' without any truth values assigned--why is that? @Dims

Comment: @QuietThud `If[ condition, true clause, false clause, non-true-or-false-clause]`

Comment: Thank you @belisarius. =) I'd appreciate a recommendation as far as a Math. programming learning source goes--the Documentation works better as a reference.

Comment: @QuietThud http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[If[p, q, Not[q]], {p, q}, All]
```